# Incrementing the value by for loop in time

Tags: javascript

Hey guys i have tried to loop with the for loop within a time limit.

The code is

```
var l = 0;
var m = setInterval(function(){ for(i=0;i<5;i++) { console.log(i); }  }, l++);
if(l == 500) {
clearInterval(m);
}
```

As we all know the code `for(i=0;i<5;i++) { console.log(i); }` prints `0,1,2,3,4` ..i just want the value to be incremented everytime and stops when it reaches 500 milliseconds..

When i run the code above the incrementation isn't stopping when it reaches 500 time limit.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You're setting l++ in the interval time not within the for loop which means the interval timer runs after every 1ms.

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - C-Link Nepal see i just want to stop looping when it reaches 500..can you provide the code if you know

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal - C-Link Nepal do i need to remove l++ ??

Comment: there you need to set the time interval what you want to run after every ??? ms

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal can you please the working code as an answer ..it would be helpful for me thanx'

Comment: @lovemysql your code is just fine. Simply put the condition to check "l" inside setInterval(). It should work. Check my answer.

Comment: can anyone tell me why this downvote is for ..:/

Answer (score 1):

Your l variable is being incremented to 1, once, and used for the interval length. It will stay at 1 forever in your example.

To run your loop every 100 milliseconds, for 500 milliseconds, you'd need to do something like this. Not sure if this is the result you're looking for, but will hopefully help. Note the interval length which is now 100.

```js
var l = 0;

var m = setInterval(function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) { 
        console.log(i);
    }

    l++;
    if (l === 5) {
        clearInterval(m);
    }
}, 100);
```

Comment: I've edited my answer. This will run every tenth of second, 5 times. Not sure if that's what you're after, but in javascript, timing is not consistent between browsers. Generally, picking an interval over 50 milliseconds will be more reliable, but not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Actualy your max value of l will be 4, so its never get to 500...

```
var l = 0;
var m = setInterval(function(){

    (l < 100) ? l++ : stop();

}, 100);

function stop(){
    clearInterval(m);
}
```

Comment: The max value of l in the question is actually 1, not 4, and this code will run every tenth of a second, and last 10 seconds.